# Is it possible to do XOR operation using 32-bit system on a 16 digit number?

Tags: binary

I am trying to perform the bitwise XOR operation on a 32-bit system where both numbers are 16-digit decimals (base 10).

However, the largest unsigned integer number enterable in the 32-bit system is 4,294,967,295. My background isn't really in computational theory. Is there a way I can still do the XOR operation using two 16-digit numbers even though my system is 32-bit?

If not, I assume the only way is to write my own XOR operation?

Comment: Convert the base 10 numbers to base 2^32 digits. Xor the digits of the two numbers bitwise. Convert the result back to decimal.  If you're using a language with a 64-bit integer type, all this will be done for you by language constructs.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in a language with 64-bit integer types, then it is likely to take care of the details of mapping 64-bit operations onto 32-bit instructions. For example, in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t xor2(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    return a ^ b;
}

int main(void) {
    uint64_t a = 1234567890123456;
    uint64_t b = 9876543210654321;
    printf("%" PRIu64 " + %" PRIu64" = %" PRIu64, a, b, xor2(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

You can check out what a 32-bit ARM compiler does with this [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PL2-_q).

Comment: Thanks for the great idea, Gene!  The language itself is actually 32-bit itself, which caused the problem.  But I can use your answer here and see if I can extend it to my 32-bit language

Comment: @RuiNian What language doesn't support 64-bit ints?  Must be an old beast...

Comment: Ohhhhh yea its a dinosaur.  It only supports up to 32-bit ints. And unfortunately, we must use it to replicate some Java code that we have.  The Java code does quite a bit of 16-digit calculations and conversion has definitely been a struggle.